# How do I limit access to a custom field type I have created so that it can only be attached to certain bundles of content?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom field class. I would like to limit it to specific content types and bundles that I will choose when my custom module is installed and as other content types meet certain criteria. I don't want it to be available at /admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/add-field

Is hook_form_alter on the add-field page form my only option or is there an Annotation or API I can use to mark my field as "not available to this content" similar to the way FieldWidgets can be marked as applicable to only certain field types?

Note: I was also planning to add a ConstraintValidator to the field so that it won't validate if added to the wrong content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I will answer with what I found:

In order to make a field type be unavailable on the manage fields page there is an option in the FieldType annotion plugin called `$no_ui` which must be set to `TRUE` as documented [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Annotation%21FieldType.php/property/FieldType%3A%3Ano_ui/8.9.x).

Then the field can still be added to specific content types using `BaseFieldDefinition::create()` in `hook_entity_base_field_info` or to bundles using the less common `hook_entity_bundle_field_info` plus `hook_entity_field_storage_info`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define field types which are only applicable to certain bundles. I think you need hook_form_alter for the form where the fields are chosen for a bundle to achieve that.